# How to stop adding new SOLines in Sales Orders Screen according to a condition in Acumatica

Tags: customization, acumatica

I want to stop adding new lines to a sales order based on a condition in **Acumatica**. How can I do this.?

I tried adding the following. But It did not worked.

protected void SOLine_RowInserting(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
{

```
        var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

        if (row == null) return;

        //Condition

        if(Condition == true)

       {

                   Base.Transaction.Delete(row);

        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `AllowInsert` cache property to false from the context of `RowSelected` event.

```
void _(Events.RowSelected<SOLine> e, PXRowSelected baseMethod)
{
    baseMethod(e.Cache, e.Args);

    bool canInsertCondition = false;
    Base.Transaction.Cache.AllowInsert = canInsertCondition;
}
```